# How can I send an email with autoGenerateEditButton set to True?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

We would like an email sent out when an update is made.

How can I do this when autogenerateEditButton of gridview set to true?

Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvRowDataBound" **onRowUpdated="btnSendEmail_Click"** AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date_stamp" HeaderText="Entry Date" ReadOnly = "true"
            SortExpression="date_stamp" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My email code is on codebehind called `sub btnSendEmail_Click()`.

```
    Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdatedEventArgs)
        Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        'Dim param As SqlParameter
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        Dim sqlStr As String = ""
        Dim sqlStrD As String = ""

        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Database_DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
more - not posted
more - not posted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a 'Send Email' button and rely on the user to manually click it, why not create a hook to handle the Gridview's RowUpadated event?

```
  void GridView1_RowUpdated(Object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {

    // Indicate whether the update operation succeeded.
    if(e.Exception == null)
    {
      int index = GridView1.EditIndex;
      GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows(index);
      //example to pull the data from a cell to send it to your function
      SendEmail(row.Cells(0).Text);

      Message.Text = "Row updated successfully. Email Sent!";
    }
    else
    {
      e.ExceptionHandled = true;
      Message.Text = "An error occurred while attempting to update the row. No email sent.";
    }

  }
```

VB code:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdatedEventArgs)

    ' Indicate whether the update operation succeeded.
    If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
        Dim index As Integer = GridView1.EditIndex
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        'example to pull the data from a cell to send it to your function
        SendEmail(row.Cells(0).Text)

        Message.Text = "Row updated successfully. Email Sent!"
    Else
        e.ExceptionHandled = True
        Message.Text = "An error occurred while attempting to update the row. No email sent."
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT to comment**
I used the parameter as an example to show you how to pull the value from the gridview if you wanted to pass it. Something like this:

SendEmail

```
Protected Sub SendEmail(ByVal RowNumber as Integer)
    Try
        Const ToAddress As String = "ThierEmail@domain.com"
        Const FromAddress As String = "YourEmail@domain.com"
        Dim Subject As String = "Row Updated"

        Dim mm As New MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress)
        mm.Subject = Subject
        mm.IsBodyHtml = False

        mm.Priority = MailPriority.High
        mm.Body =  String.Format("Row ID {0} was updated.",RowNumber)

        'Send the email
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
          smtp.Send(mm)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'You should catch your error here
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you zeroef; you are great. One question. I see that you have a param inside SendEmail - SendEmail(row.Cells(0).Text). Does that mean that I need to add a parameter to my btnSendEmail_Click sub? If yes, what should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have `btnSendEmail_Click()` handle the GridView's [`RowEditing` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx). In your ASP code, you should have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
     OnRowEditing="btnSendEmail_Click"
     ...
     AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    '...code to send email...
```

Comment: Justin, I can't thank you enough for your response. Do I have to have those 2 arguments? I am getting following error message:  Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs)'. 
 Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs)'.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be onrowUpdating since I am trying to update? I am newbie so I am just curious.

Comment: That depends on when you want to send the email. The RowUpdating event does sound more appropriate to me. As for your error message, you could try making `e` a plain `EventArgs` object instead.

Comment: Experts, could you please help me figure out what I could be doing wrong? I am still getting these errors: Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs)'. Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Protected Sub btnSendEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs)' I don't want to dump a bunch of codes here but i have updated above to somehow reflect what I am trying to do.